# How to find dates that are within 5 minutes of now()

Tags: mysql

I have a column name called `last_activity` that is of type DATETIME. (so. 2021-01-03 00:00:00). I want to find all rows which are within 5 minutes of now. I attempted the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE last_activity >  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

I get 0 rows, even though the activity is within 5 minutes (I know because the database says so). How can I fix this?

Comment: @Dharman I asked it with php tag because the query is done through php and thought it would maybe cause different results. Also i did search and all the options did not work so i thought id ask the question with my problem.

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY SURE that `last_activity` column is defined as DATETIME. Please show us the schema. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: RE: Your AM and PM comment, DATETIME columns are 24Hr not 12Hr based always. Hence my question about data type? Also on a test datebase I run your code and get the right result, So whats really going on here is wierd to say the least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get the difference in minutes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, last_activity, NOW())) <= 5
```

Comment: it still returns 0. It says in my databse in mysql 08:35 which is correct, but it wont work. even if teh time is 08:35

Comment: @newbie12345 My query returns the rows that have a max difference of 5 mins from NOW(). The function NOW() returns *the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' or YYYYMMDDhhmmss format, depending on whether the function is used in string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the session time zone.* Did you check what NOW() returns in your MySql server? Execute `SELECT NOW();`

Comment: i did this ``$n= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT NOW()");`` and it returned an error.

Comment: Wouldn't this be bad performance? Does it use INDEX?

Comment: Do you have access to phpMyAdmin or Workbench. Its easier to do it there

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do will try it there

Comment: @Dharman that the query returned false

Comment: @newbie12345 That is not an error. That means you didn't enable error reporting. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks man, I know the issue i think. Now is returning 22:50 which is correct as its pm here, where the datetime i am inserting is 08:30. I assume to get it to 24 hour i need to do ``date('Y-m-d H:i:s');``?

Comment: @newbie12345 None of this makes sense. 24h/12h is only important when you display the date not when you compare.

Comment: @newbie12345 what is the data type of `last_activity`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for being patient i really appreciate it. approved ticked :)

Comment: @forpas I don't want to sound rude but its clearly stated in the question that its ``DATETIME``

Comment: @newbie12345 this is what I read in your question. But you mentioned something about pm or am which is not relevant when the data type is DATETIME and you compare it with NOW().

Comment: I don't get it. What was the problem? Was it NOW() +5 minutes like the answer suggests to solve or was it something unrelated? What did RiggsFolly say that helped to fix it?

Comment: @Dharman I get the feeling that the OP was assuming the 8:30 and 22:30 were the same thing, so this is really just a bit of a non-issue brought about by lack of .... sleep maybe :)